# Block certain commands

Tags: bash-scripting

I want to block all commands like that

```bsh
mv (or cp) /myFolder/myFile /media/*
```

(* = all the files into /media)

Is that possible with a simple script or does it need a real program ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  There are way more ways to transfer data than just `mv` and `cp`.

Comment: I know theres way more possibitlities, i don't need to block all copy over the OS, i just want that the commands mv and cp who respect my case don't succeed

Comment: Thats not a problem if the copy is possible by an other method. The topic concern just 2 commands

Comment: "like" strictly equal to the command that i described
And be sure that it isnt a XY problem, i just want it for cp and mv, the copy can work otherwise

Comment: The source is absolute, it's myFile and nothing other, the destination is all the folder, files... of /media/

Comment: I think that block all the copy of a certain file over the OS will be too heavy to accomplish, it will need a program or hours of scripting. For me if the cp and mv don't work with a script, its absolutely enough for me, i don't care about the other way to do it

Comment: OK. Is `/media/*` a pattern that should tell us what targets you want to block? Or is it a literal string you would type in the shell and get blocked?

Comment: Not a literal one. It just means "/media/myMedia" will be blocked as well as "/media/myOtherOneMedia"

Comment: Now it makes little more sense. You should [edit] the question and clarify. Still I think the question is not useful. Blocking `mv` and `cp` (if possible) while not blocking other ways will give you *nothing*. Unless there's something you're not telling us, but then the whole thing probably qualifies as XY problem.

Comment: It's reaaaally not an XY problem, for me it's really a problem about the cp and mv commands, i don't want to get something, i just want to block the action of cp and mv, for real

Comment: Chmod mv and cp into oblivion acceptable?

Comment: I just want for what i wrote on the post, not all the command

Comment: What the scope of this block should be? System-wide? certain users? you? single shell?

Comment: I don't really care, if it work for a unique shell session, all the system, or other it's okay for me. the simplest

Comment: I think tjis is a bad question as its very vague. If you are not root, you can play with file ownership or for finer grain control look at selinux. To go sll the way you might need a wrapper arround the cp and mv command, or possibly a complex alias in your shell to overlay dome checks.

Comment: The alias way seems very interesting, considering only the mv and cp command are the problem, and not the whole copy procedure

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 707 /media/`

No one can now write to /media/ - this means they can't delete files in it either, but they can't copy or move files into it's directory without being root.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1453766/block-certain-commands#comment2192900_1453766